# iPhone In App Email

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have my application sending an email, but is there a way to put a photo in my email above the text i'm sending.  Kind of like a header to display my logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach an image using the MFMailComposeViewController it is **always** displayed at the bottom of the message (under your text, but above the signature) and this cannot be changed in the current version of the framework.

It is possible, however, to encode your image data into base64 and place this directly in the HTML body of your app.  I won't include the code here (you can easily google it) because this is tricky and problematic since not all readers will interpret this correctly.

If this is a header image that will be the same for all emails you can put this on a server somewhere and then include an `<img>` tag in your HTML email body that references this file.

If this is a dynamic image you can have your app upload it to one of the many image hosting sites, retrieve the url and again include it as the `src` of an `<img>` tag in your HTML email body.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Action for submenu Email Button
- (IBAction)emailButtonPressed {
[delegate playSound:@"Click_16"];

if (connectionStatus == YES) 
{

    if (maxCounter) 
    {
        NSString *filename = (NSString *)[self currentImageObject:kSerialKey AtIndex:imageCounter];

        NSString* documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

            // set up image data for email
        NSString *imageFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imageFile];

            // set up mail view controller for message
        MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        if (controller != nil) 
        {
            controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [controller setSubject:@"Email Subject"];
            [controller setMessageBody:@"Check out this picture" isHTML:NO];
            [controller addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:filename];
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

        }

        [controller release];

    }

    else 
        [self genericAlert:@"There are no pictures to email."];

}

else
    [self genericAlert:@"You are not connected to the internet.  Please connect and try again."];

}

// email delegate method to dismiss window
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code. The documentsDirectory variable is the application's documents directory: `[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: this code will still place the image below the message and above the signature.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename` method from the *MFMailComposeViewController* class.

Here's a [great example of this](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/email/how-to-send-email-with-attachments-example-using-iphone-camera-to-email-a-photo.html) that shows taking an image from the camera and then sending it an an email message!

Comment: I don't want to send this as an attachment but rather display above some text

Comment: You will see the image at the bottom of your email and above the user's signature. You can't customize this using this framework.